# Dealing with too generic questions

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

First of all, the question linked below is just to illustrate my more general concerns.

After this question [Which plugin should I use to get started with Jenkins to manage mainframe components in PDS format?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/292/which-plugin-should-i-use-to-get-started-with-jenkins-to-manage-mainframe-compon?noredirect=1#comment351_292) which has a real value for a canonical point of view.
I've the feeling we have a problem trying to create canonical questions.

The problem I see here is that it miss a practical goal. There's no clue of what is intended to do with jenkins, which by nature is very volatile from just linting jobs to Continuous Delivery pipeline.

I assume this is due to the wish to create a canonical question from problems encountered or question we had ourselves and willing to write them in a less 'personal' way so they are useful to more people.

There's others examples which have the same kind of problem in my opinion.

- [What is a 'Feature Flag Toggle' and when to use them (or not)?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/revisions/344/1) first revision, which has been edited in a better format
- [How is Ansible different from simply running a provisioning bash shell in Vagrant?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/342/how-is-ansible-different-from-simply-running-a-provisioning-bash-shell-in-vagran) which could be worded differently by taking an actual use case so answers can focus on what gives an advantage over the other and extend on a more generic comparison
- [How to design authentication and authorization in micro-services architecture?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/revisions/253/1) first revision, which again should be more focused.
- [How to design authentication and authorization in micro-services architecture?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/253/how-to-design-authentication-and-authorization-in-micro-services-architecture) same as above in its current version, still with a generic goal.

What I fear is that either answers will be very long (if they fit in 30k chars) or that it will attract a bunch of vague answers on what is better to do on answer's author opinion, not exactly addressing the concerns and/or missing part of the question by focusing on only one point.

While we can downvote, and then delete bad answers, this may create a lot of clean up work which would be better spend elsewhere.

So my question is: should we not aim at more focused and practical questions to avoid this ?

Like those:

- [How to persuade developers to start using feature flag toggles?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-persuade-developers-to-start-using-feature-flag-toggles)
- [How can I communicate queue-based processing delays to non-technical team members?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/370/how-can-i-communicate-queue-based-processing-delays-to-non-technical-team-member)

Comment: Interesting question, but before posting "my" recommendation ("some day"), I suggest you try to rework your 2nd parg (with the 4 inks) in it. Even if it was only to avoid your question looses (some) value if (eg) "I" would delete "my" comment you linked to (just include a reevant quote here?). And maybe also relace the "other", "which" and "kind" link-titles with the actual titles of what they link to (just in case these linked questions get deleted). Just a suggestion ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I hope you don't feel targeted personally , my concerns are really on the questions format. I'll see how to reword this after lunch. I'm probably formatted by meta SO where linking multiples questions on a sentence is ´usual' but I see why it could be bad here.

Comment: Don't worry, I don't feel like so (if ever needed I'll "say what I think ... that is my REAL rep ...). And my "delete my own comment" from before (now deleted), was only to bring to your attention the "feature flag/toggle"-link thing (= delete of my own comment) that I could "use" (abuse?) to ruin part of your question here (which is definitely not what "I" plan to do, though some day a mod may do so instead of me ...). About meta.SO: I'm waiting for a miracle to happen there some day (contact me for details if needed),